# How to improve contour detection of holes in white wall

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, canny-operator

[image]
I want to identify the black spots in this image.

While Canny edge detection captures most of the features,
[image]

using `contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresholded, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` only detects a few isolated points. Is there a way to improve this?
[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image1 = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\54-0461100-01\Desktop\img_process\Daphnia\WIN_20231103_09_47_45_Pro.jpg")

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_, thresholded = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)  

thresholded = cv2.dilate(thresholded, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('thresholded1', thresholded)

thresholded = cv2.Canny(thresholded, 100, 200)
cv2.imshow('thresholded2', thresholded)
cv2.imwrite("thresholded2.jpg", thresholded)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresholded, cv2.RETR_LIST  , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)#cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE

object_count = 0
img_with_boxes = image1.copy()

for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area < 15:  #
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        img_with_boxes = cv2.rectangle(img_with_boxes, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        object_count += 1

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(img_with_boxes, f'Black Dots: {object_count}', (10, 30), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite("detected_black_dots.jpg", img_with_boxes)
cv2.imshow('Black Dots Detected', img_with_boxes)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: your detection approach is correct, but the condition that you use `if area < 15: ` filters the big contours (big black holes), remove that condition to see all holes!

Comment: Don't use Canny.  Threshold your image so that the black holes become white and the rest black (invert if necessary). Then use morphology to clean up any small white spots that are not the ones you want. Then get contours from that.

Comment: @bhomaidan90 The situation you mentioned has been adjusted by me. In theory, I have managed to capture small black spots, so there's no reason why I shouldn't be able to capture larger black spots.

Comment: @fmw42
' thresholded = cv2.dilate(thresholded, kernel, iterations=1)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresholded, kernel, iterations=1)
thresholded = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel, iterations=1)'
The following is the result.
https://imgur.com/a/vgX8wbl
https://imgur.com/eEmyZaO
It might be related to binarization. With `cv2.findContours`, the contours are identified from white areas, but my black spots are black. I feel like the solution is almost there; I'll look into it further.

Comment: Threshold your image so that the black spots become white and the rest of the image becomes black. If necessary invert the image so that you get your spots as white.  Use morphology if you need to remove extraneous spots or filter once you have your contours.  Once the black spots are white, you can get contours. Contours only work on white regions.

Comment: https://imgur.com/9g1Nsd2
Modified Code :

"for contour in contours:
    area = len(contour)
    if area < 100:  
        cv2.drawContours(img_with_boxes, [contour], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        object_count += 1
"

This snippet is suitable for drawing the contours of black spots based on a specific threshold of contour length. However, it might not offer convenience in computing the size and position of each individual black spot.

Comment: @bhomaidan90 In the end, I found that you were correct. When I printed the area value, it turned out to be much larger than I had imagined.
`area value:620.5
area value:503.0
area value:621.0
area value:361.5
area value:398.0
area value:430.0
area value:203.0
area value:321.5
`